# Conditional recoding big set of variables into NA

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm looking for a solution to recode huge sets of variables into NA.
This should work like:

```
if (df$check1==1) then df$Q1,Q2,Q3....Q100 <-NA
if (df$check2==1) then df$R1,R2,R3....R500 <-NA
```

I'd like to keep list of variable names to change in separate lists (CSV).
I thought about `ifelse` or `recode` but not sure how to apply it to set variables on the output side. In `mutate_if` we have conditions on target variables..., so I got lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could use `mutate` with `across`

```
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>%
    mutate(across(Q1:Q100,  ~ replace(.x, check1 == 1, NA)), 
           across(R1:R500,  ~ replace(.x, check2 == 1, NA)))
```

---

In `base R`, we may use

```
qcols <- paste0("Q", 1:100)
rcols <- paste0("R", 1:500)
df[df$check1 == 1, qcols] <- NA
df[df$check2 == 1, rcols] <- NA
```